# Getting every child widget of a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to get all of the children of a Tkinter widget, then get the children's children etc.?

Basically I want all of the widgets within one entire window.

**Edit :**
I found a solution utilizing Bryan's line :

```
def all_children (wid) :
    _list = wid.winfo_children()

    for item in _list :
        if item.winfo_children() :
            _list.extend(item.winfo_children())

    return _list
```

Comment: For searchers (such as myself) the key word is "recursively", eg "How do I recursively iterate over all children of a widget."

Comment: wont reading and adding into the same list cause for loop to iterate forever.?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [winfo_children](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/getting-every-child-widget-of-a-tkinter-window).

Recursive like this:

```
def all_children(wid, finList=None, indent=0):
    finList = finList or []
    print(f"{'   ' * indent}{wid=}")
    children = wid.winfo_children()
    for item in children:
        finList.append(item)
        all_children(item, finList, indent + 1)
    return finList
```

Comment: Bryan's link no longer is active try this one instead [Every Child](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/getting-every-child-widget-of-a-tkinter-window)