# Is there a way to call the amount of labels or widgets there are currently open in a TKinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so for example

```
window = Tk()

lbl = Label(text='abc')
lbl.place(x=1, y=1)

lbl2 = Label(text='ABC')
lbl2.place(x=2, y=2)

numOfWidgets = window.amount
print(str(numOfWidgets))

>>> 2
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: When you say "call the amount", did you mean "_count_ the amount"?

Comment: Read [Basic Widget Methods - Widget.winfo_children-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting every child widget of a Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290071/getting-every-child-widget-of-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 0):

The method `winfo_children` will return the children of a given window. You can use that information to iterate through all of the widgets if you need a count of all widgets in an application.

In your case, `len(window.winfo_children())` will return `2`.